# Must declare the scalar variable error when inserting into Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

My webpage consist of a  GridView, which allows the user to view, edit, and insert data. The data is inserted using a DetailView-Form, which opens via a javaScript-type window. One of the columns in the GridView consist of a company_guid, which is captured via a session that is setup in a log-in page.   I'm attempting to capture the user's company_guid and log it into the Grid upon inserting data. I'm able to view and edit the Gridview, but I get the following error when I try to insert: **Must declare the scalar variable "@companyguid"**.

**The following is my Hypertext - GridView:**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Part_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  
     AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
     <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Part_ID" HeaderText="Part_ID" 
             SortExpression="Part_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" Visible="false" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Company_guid" HeaderText="Company_guid" 
             SortExpression="Company_guid" Visible="false"  />

         <asp:BoundField DataField="Part_Name" HeaderText="Part_Name" 
             SortExpression="Part_Name" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Part_Desc" HeaderText="Part_Desc" 
             SortExpression="Part_Desc" />

         <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" 
             SortExpression="Active" />

        <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateDate" HeaderText="UpdateDate" 
             SortExpression="UpdateDate" />

         <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateBy" HeaderText="UpdateBy" 
             SortExpression="UpdateBy" />

     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**The Detail View (this is what opens via the JavaScript Window):**

```
<asp:DetailsView
        id="dtlCarrier"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        AutoGenerateInsertButton="True"
        AutoGenerateRows="False"
        DefaultMode="Insert"
        Runat="server" DataKeyNames="Part_ID">
        <Fields>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Part_Name" HeaderText="Part_Name" 
                SortExpression="Part_Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Part_Desc" HeaderText="Part_Desc" 
                SortExpression="Part_Desc" />

              <asp:CheckBoxField
            DataField="Active"
            HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateDate" HeaderText="UpdateDate" 
                SortExpression="UpdateDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UpdateBy" HeaderText="UpdateBy" 
                SortExpression="UpdateBy" />

        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView> 



<!-- the sql data source -->  
    <asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ShipperNotificationConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Part]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Part SET Part_Name=@Part_Name,
    Part_Desc=@Part_Desc, Active=@Active, UpdateDate=@UpdateDate, UpdateBy=@UpdateBy  
    WHERE Part_ID=@Part_ID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT Part (company_guid,Part_Name,Part_Desc,Active,UpdateDate,UpdateBy)
            VALUES (@companyguid,@Part_Name,@Part_Desc,@Active,@UpdateDate,@UpdateBy)"          
   runat="server" 
        />
```

The code behind:

```
Public Class SupplierPartsMgmt
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    'Globally declare my variable to hold the company_guid
    Dim companyGuid As String = ""

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        'initialized companyGuid to the session varible, which is capured/stored via the log-in pg
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            companyGuid = Session("numrecord").ToString
        Else
            companyGuid = Session("numrecord").ToString
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
        'Dim companyGuid As String = ""

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(companyGuid) Then
            SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("companyguid", companyGuid)
            SqlDataSource1.Insert()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Could I please get some help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the @ in this line:

```
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("companyguid", companyGuid)
```

@ is only needed while writing the query to indicate query parameters.

And if you still need the @, i think you need to declare the <`InsertParameters`> elements under your `asp:SqlDataSource` element.

**Option #1**

You could declare a session based insert parameter directly as follows:

```
<InsertParameters>
   <asp:SessionParameter Name="companyguid" SessionField="companyguid" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>
```

**Option #2**

You can also set the company guid parameter value in the oninserting command as follows:

```
<InsertParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="companyguid" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>
```

OnInserting="On_Inserting" - add this attribute to your SQL Data Source

```
protected void On_Inserting(Object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@companyguid"].Value = valueFromSession;
}
```

Comment: I dropped the @ to reflect the following (I modified the code snippet in my original post): SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("companyguid", companyGuid) ...but I still get the same error message. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions. Thank you

Comment: added a couple more options to my answer. please try.